# How can I represent probability in a pie chart?

Tags: pie-chart

I'm super new to R and wanted to make a pie chart of the results found from a 6 faced die. From what I understand, this is supposed to throw the 6-faced die 500 times, and then map out the results in a pie chart.
It seems fairly simple, but the pie chart splits into 500 ways. What am I doing wrong?

```
die <- 1:6
result <- sample(die, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
pie(result, labels = die)
```

Comment: `?table`; do your plot on the output of that for a display of counts (or scale that by the total count for proportions). (A pie chart is a poor choice for this by the way; I'd typically use a variant of `plot(table(...))` to show such results.)

Comment: This is essentially off-topic, but I love that the first sentence in ***Note*** in the documentation for `pie()` is "*Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information.*"

Comment: I have been using `R` every day for over a decade, have posted a thousand `R` solutions here on CV, and have never *once* invoked `pie`.  (But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451376/919 ;-).) Following @Glen_b's recommendation, I looked at `pie(table(sample.int(6, 500, replace = TRUE)))`.  Rather pretty -- nice pastel colors rarely seen in any other `R` functions -- and quite useless! For the record, this function defaults to a cycle of six colors, `c("white", "lightblue", "mistyrose", "lightcyan", "lavender", "cornsilk")`.

Comment: The example is perhaps a little too simple, since `die` is both the population data and the labels for the chart.  An example with an unfair die: `die <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6); result <- sample(die, size = 500, replace = TRUE); Table = table(result); Table; pie(Table, labels=labels(Table)[[1]]); round(prop.table(table(result)), 2)`

Comment: @SalMangiafico not super important but `die<-rep(1:6,c(5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2))` would save some typing, alternatively just directly go `sample(6,500,replace=TRUE,p=c(5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2))`

Answer (score 2):

You want something inheriting from `table` class:

```
pie(table(result))
```