# Generating uniformly distributed particles on a $n$-dimensional flat torus or periodic hypercube

Tags: self-study, sampling, simulation, uniform-distribution, random-generation

I am trying to generate evenly distributed particles in an $n$-dimensional flat torus or a periodic hypercube.

I am not sure if any of this approaches suffices. Can you suggest alternative methods for generating evenly distributed particles in this space or how to correct any of these?

### First approach:

Sampling $\varphi = \arccos(1-2u)$ with $u \in U[0,1]$ for the azimutal angle of the 3D unit sphere $\left( \mathcal{S}^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3} \right)$ prevents accumulation of points near the poles being the polar angle sample, where $\theta = 2\pi v$ with $v \in U[0,1]$.

I was wondering if "copying" this behaviour by sampling $$\vec{x} = \{ 2 \cdot \arccos(1-2u_{i}): u_{i} \in U[0,1] \}_{i=1}^{n} \in [0,2 \pi]^{n}$$
would be enough to generate $n$ random points in an $n$-dimensional flat torus or hypercube, where each dimension has length $2\pi$.

I have run a little simulation for 2D and 3D and it looks like the corners (which represent the same point) aren't very likely to have much particles, which is reasonable given the functional form of the $\arccos$.

### Another approach:

Considering the map into the torus

$$\sigma: (x_1,x_2) \in [0,2\pi]^{2} \mapsto \left[ (1+\cos(x_1))\cdot \sin(x_2), (1+\cos(x_1))\cdot \sin(x_2), \sin(x_1) \right] \in \mathbb{T}^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$$

Obtaining the differential volume element $\| \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x_1} \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x_2} \| = 1+\cos(x_1)$, which also gives the enclosed area $A = \int \int \| \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x_1} \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x_2} \| dx_1 dx_2 = (2\pi)^2$

Then, obtaining the marginal probability density functions $f(\cdot)$ and the cumulative probability functions $F(\cdot)$,

$$f(x_1) =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1+\cos(x_1) dx_2 = \frac{1+\cos(x_1)}{2\pi} \Longrightarrow \\ \Longrightarrow F(x_1) = \int_{0}^{x_1} f(x_1) dx_1 = \frac{x_1 + \sin(x_1)}{2\pi}$$

$$f(x_2) =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1+\cos(x_1) dx_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \Longrightarrow \\ \Longrightarrow F(x_2) = \int_{0}^{x_2} f(x_2) dx_2 = \frac{x_2}{2\pi}$$

I tried to also sample $(x_1,x_2)$ from $u_1,u_2 \in U[0,1]$ by computing $x_1 = F^{-1}(u_1)$ (numerically solved) and $x_2 = F^{-1}(u_2)= 2\pi u_2$.

Note that the inverse function makes sense since $F(\cdot)$ is monotone and bijective (inyective and surjective) in $[0,1]$.

For higher dimensions ($n>2$) the mapping $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n) $ would be modified accordingly:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma_1(\vec{x}) &= \left[ 1+\cos(x_1) \right] \cos(x_2) \\
\sigma_2(\vec{x}) &= \left[ 1+\cos(x_1) \right] \sin(x_2) \cos(x_3) \\
\dots & \\
\sigma_{n-2}(\vec{x}) &= \left[ 1+\cos(x_1) \right] \sin(x_2) \cdot \dots \cdot \sin(x_{n-3}) \cos(x_{n-2}) \\
\sigma_{n-1}(\vec{x}) &= \left[ 1+\cos(x_1) \right] \sin(x_2) \cdot \dots \cdot \sin(x_{n-2}) \cos(x_{n-1}) \\
\sigma_{n}(\vec{x}) &= \left[ 1+\cos(x_1) \right] \sin(x_2) \cdot \dots \cdot \sin(x_{n-1}) \sin(x_{n-1}) \\
\end{array}
$$

### Note:

I have used as reference http://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/

Comment: i don't know much about "n-d flat toroids" nor "periodic hypercubes", but in 3D, we can view a torus as a sheet of paper rolled up into a cigarette and then with its ends joined together. By sampling uniformly on this sheet of paper and transforming the samples, we can thus sample uniformly. Think this might be generalizable?

Comment: This is a strange question, because the image of your map is not a torus: it's a patch in $\mathbb R^2.$ Ordinarily, one would coordinatize the flat torus using $n$ real numbers modulo $1;$ that is, $T^n = \mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$ is a quotient of abelian groups.  Consequently, you can generate uniformly distributed points (with respect to the invariant measure induced by Lebesgue measure) by drawing realizations from $n$ *iid* Uniform$(0,1)$ variables.  Please, then, edit this post to clarify what exactly you mean by a "flat torus" if it's not what I just described.

Comment: @John I think you have the right idea.  However, that 3D embedding of the torus is not flat: it has positive (Gaussian) curvature around the outer rim and negative curvature on the inner rim (speaking informally).  Generating uniformly distributed points on that surface is not too easy.  To envision a *flat* torus you need at least four dimensions.  One coordinate system consists of the points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ in $\mathbb R^4$ where the parameters $(\theta,\phi)\subset[0,2\pi)^2.$

Comment: BTW, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451376/919 I posted examples based on generating uniformly distributed points on high-dimensional flat tori.