# CLT, Euclidean Distances and Means

Tags: random-variable, central-limit-theorem, distance

This may sound like a rather odd question but I have stumbled upon a distribution of means that resembles a normal, but I am not sure whether it is possible to prove that it is indeed one or not. Here is the setup.

Suppose I take a sample of $n$ independent and identically distributed random vectors/variables $ x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ (I did use a specific distribution but I don't think that matters). We now find the Euclidean distance of each random variable/vector to all the other variables and find an average. Thus, for each variable $j = 1,...,n$ in the sample we have:

$$
Y_j = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i \neq j} ||x_j,x_i||
$$

Now if I increase $n$ and repeatedly plot the distribution of these variables, I get something that increasingly looks like a normal distribution. Is this a fluke or is there something deeper here that I am not understanding? After all, the $Y_j$ variables are not independent of one another neither are the Euclidean distances.

EDIT: To give more details for context. Each random vector $\mathbf{x_i}$ has 8094 components. Each component $m$ is derived independently as follows:

$$
x_{im} = \min \{z_1,...,z_{K_m}\}
$$

Here $z_1,...,z_{K_m}$ are draws from a discrete uniform with parameters $[1,108]$. I have a fixed vector which specifies the $K_m$ for each component (i.e. the number of draws for each component).

Here is the relevant R code for the simulation. I note that *total* is a dataframe of 8094 rows and one column called *num*. Any vector of integers should do the job.

```
simulated_vectors <- replicate(10000, {
samples <- lapply(total$num, function(n) sample(1:108, n, replace = TRUE))
  min_values <- sapply(samples, min)
  return(min_values)
})

mat <- t(simulated_vectors)
distances <- dist(mat)

distances_matrix <- as.matrix(distances)

average_distances <- apply(distances_matrix, 1, function(row) {
  (sum(row) - min(row)) / (length(row) - 1)
})

 hist(average_distances, main = "Histogram of Average Distances", xlab = "Average Distance")
```

Comment: this is not mean, as the number of pairs is greater than $n$

Comment: That's true but I am finding the average distance a variable is from all others. That is why I would end up with $n$ average distances.

Comment: More details would be helpful.  For small vector dimensions it is geometrically evident, and easily demonstrable with simulation, that these mean distances shouldn't generally look at all Normal.

Comment: also what does it mean to "look like normal" to you? Chi distribution looks normal visually for some parameters

Comment: Very true, I will provide more details in an edit. If it's Chi-squared that's great too, but unlikely.

Comment: I have also added some R code to repeat what I am doing. Hopefully that should make the explanation make more sense too.

Comment: (1) Please warn your readers that **your code will take a long time to run**-- and might take forever depending on values in `total$num`.  Do us all a favor by streamlining it.  Here is an adequate version that runs in under one second: `df <- data.frame(num = rpois(8094, 3) + 1);
n.sim <- 200;
n <- 108;
X <- sapply(df$num, \(k) ceiling(n * (1 - runif(n.sim)^(1/k))));
d <- colSums(as.matrix(dist(X))) / n.sim;
qqnorm(d)` (2) See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/236631/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451376/919, *inter alia.* Change `8094` to, say, `2` in the code and rerun it.